# Query based two datetime fields

Tags: mysql

I want to create a MySQL query that gives me a selection of records in which the logout time is greater than logon time or login time is more than 2 hours ago.

Now my question is this possible in MySQL? 
If so how?

This what did try:

```
select * from `some_table`
where `loguittijd` > `logintijd` 
OR `logintijd` < NOW()
```

Comment: Yes, it's very easy. Just write the two conditions, and connect them with `OR`.

Comment: This is about as simple as SQL queries get, is there some wrinkle that makes it difficult? Are the login and logout times in different rows?

Comment: Oke bamar, i justed added what i tryed,

Comment: It looks like you know how to do the comparison between two fields, you just don't know how to get the time for 2 hours ago.

Comment: At first i didn't know you could use >< with date and time, stupid engough i didn't try i assumed i couldn't. Asumtion is the mother off all .........why do i need tot put the where between ()?

Comment: You don't need to put the WHERE in parentheses. Some people just do it out of habit.

Comment: It's just personal style.

Comment: thanks for the pointers , i posted here becouse i got stuck. Andere becouse a replacement for learning programming. I am cuurently programming a XMLrpc authentication bridge for our computer club in the NL. The XML server processies the login request against a ldap server andere return relevant member info back in a safe way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61152/discussion-between-bas-van-den-dikkenberg-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be about right, obviously you'll need to substitute your table/column names:

```
select * from user_login where 
(logout_time > login_time OR
login_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR))
```